# How to make Microsoft Flow to notify me in teams if somebody @mention me on Azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-teams, power-automate

Currently I am able to achieve If the work item is assigned to me in Azure Devops then I will get notification.

But is there a way in **Microsoft Flow** to notify me in Teams using Flow bot if somebody **@mentioned** me on Azure devops work items or tasks?   In comments or in the description

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way in Microsoft Flow to notify me in Teams using Flow bot
>   if somebody @mentioned me on Azure devops work items or tasks? In
>   comments or in the description

For this issue ,I am afraid this feature is not feasible in ms flow. There is no such trigger in the ms flow that matches "@someone in comments or description".

If you want to be notified not just in the teams , you don't actually have to  receive notifications by using ms flow. When someone @mentioned you in the comments or description in the work item of azure devops,your account's email address will automatically receive notifications. The precondition is that your account is a member of the organization and can access this work item.
[image]

Comment: Thank you Hugh for your suggestion. The purpose of asking notification in teams is to get rid of email communication completely. And I strongly believe MSFT teams is the one single point for all kind of communication going forward. Thats why I wanted to get notified on Teams.